# Modifying existing regex, excluding some parts

Tags: python, regex

I have an expression in regex, as follow:

`r"(?:AND|OR|SUB|ADD)\([^()]*\)(?:\]\[|\[|)(|\s\[|\s)COIL\(Seq\[\d+]\.Bool\[\d+]\.\d+"`

Usually I am using it to capturing from a sentence like that:

`AND(Seq[1].Mat)AND(Type_G012.WithData)[COIL(Seq[1].Bool[93].11),XIC(Seq[1].exp)RES(Seq[1].ita)]`

So I want to extract the last "AND" or "OR" or "SUB"... also with Seq[1].Bool[93].11.
After that I am doing an additional extraction. It was working with no problems with almost everything. The problem is that I have some patterns like that.

`AND(Seq[1].Mat)AND(Type_G014.WithData)AND(Type_G015.WithData)[SET(Seq[1].WaitStep)COIL(Seq[1].Seq[93].10),AND(Seq[1].exp)RES(Seq[1].ita)]`

Then I am not capturing the last AND, OR, SUB, etc. Because now I have the SET instruction in the middle of the AND and the COIL. So I want to exclude anything diferent of `AND|OR|SUB|ADD` Because I would like to extract from the last sentence as follow:

`AND(Type_G015.WithData)[SET(Seq[1].Wait)COIL(Seq[1].Seq[93].10`

Then is the last AND before the COIL. If something could help me I am testing several things and I am messing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match both parts, you might use

```
(?:AND|OR|SUB|ADD)\([^()]+\)(?:\[SET\([^()]+\))?\[?COIL\(Seq\[\d+\]\.(?:Seq|Bool)\[\d+\]\.\d+
```

In parts

- `(?:AND|OR|SUB|ADD)` Match 1 of the alternatives
- `\([^()]+\)` Match from an opening till closing parenthesis
- `(?:\[SET\([^()]+\))?` Optionally match `[SET` and from opening till closing parenthesis
- `\[?COIL\(Seq\[\d+\]\.` Match Optional `[` and `COIL(Seq[` 1+ digits and `].`
- `(?:Seq|Bool)` Match either Seq or Bool
- `\[\d+\]\.\d+` Match `[` 1+ digits and `].` followed by 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DT0BTJ/1)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

Now I have something like that:

`AND(Type_G015.WithData)[SET(Seq[1].Wait)COIL(Seq[1].Seq[93].10`

How Can I extract just `AND(Type_G015.WithData)`. Because my idea was as follow:

`(?:AND|OR|SUB|ADD)\((.*)\)` But now I am extracting until the last parenthesis but I would like to extract everythin but only until the first closing parenthesis, just:

`AND(Type_G015.WithData)`

Between parenthesis we could be whatever less more parenthesis.

Comment: I found a solution for that. Checking this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357460/python-regex-matching-a-parenthesis-within-parenthesis