# (Regex) (Python) date missing in Regex and need to organize/listed the value

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on extract data from string, and output them into "companyID",  "date" and  "amount" ,
I have read through [Python regex: matching a parenthesis within parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357460/python-regex-matching-a-parenthesis-within-parenthesis) to output my date and amount successfully but stocking on:

**1. The "companyID" not output well

2. when mutiple string come in couldn,t list them well**

**Q1: 1. The "companyID" not output well**

```js
import re


text = "Original string:(Company_name_1)：(2032/01/15*70000 )"

# (almost there) print ( "companyID", ( re.findall (r'*/(/ \.?([ \d.]+ */)/  )',text)))
# (almost there) re.match(r'(ftp|http)://.*\.(jpg|png)$', s)

print ( "companyID", ( re.findall (r'\([^()]*(\):)$',text)))

print ( "date", ( re.findall (r'\d+[/.-]\d+[/.-]\d{2,4}',text)))

print ( "amount", ( re.findall (r'[*]\.?([ \d.]+)',text)))
```

[(pic Q1) the code and output showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYyxn.png)

**Q2 2. when mutiple string come in, couldn't list them well, and some of my date is missing in my output**

ex:
{“Company_name_1”,[{“2032/01/15" : "70000" }]}

{“Company_name_2, Subsidiary_name_1, Subsidiary_name_2”,[{"2024/1/1*20000"} ; {"2022/11/7*20000"} ; {"2023/3/6*1000"} ; {"2023/4/20*20000 "}; {"2026/5/1*8000 "};{" 2023/5/8*8000"} ; {"2005/7/27*300000 "}; {"2023/8/22*80000"} ; {"2023/8/7*60000"} ; {"2023/11/6*70000"} ; {"2004/1/19*12000"} ; {"1998/3/14*16000 "} ]}

```js
import re


text = "Original string:(Company_name_1)：(2032/01/15*70000)(Company_name_2, Subsidiary_name_1, Subsidiary_name_2):(2024/1/1*20000 ; 2022-11-7*20000 ; 2023/3/6*1000 ; 2023/4/20*20000 ; 2026/5/1*8000 ; 2023/5/8*8000 ; 2005/7/27*300000 ; 2023/8/22*80000 ; 2023/8/7*60000 ; 2023/11/6*70000 ; 2004/1/19*12000 ; 1998/3/14*16000 ; )"

# (almost there) print ( "companyID",( re.findall (r'*/(/ \.?([ \d.]+ */)/  )',text)))
# (almost there) re.match(r'(ftp|http)://.*\.(jpg|png)$', s)

print ( "companyID", ( re.findall (r'\([^()]*(\):)$',text)))

print ( "date", ( re.findall (r'\d+[/.-]\d+[/.-]\d{2,4}',text)))

print ( "amount", ( re.findall (r'[*]\.?([ \d.]+)',text)))
```

[(pic Q2)the code and outputshowing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CXYF.png)

Answer (score 0):

suggest:

1. Debug on the tool first,then use python
2. Regular expressions preferably no spaces

Comment: hi, @BugMaker I  have used the onlone regex tool https://regex101.com/ , but I haven't figure out the solution yet from yesterday. For space I will remove it later.
So if I just want the company name pop out, how can I correct?